# Groovy and Maven: CompileStatic with generics

Tags: maven, generics, groovy

Simple generic class in Groovy

```
@CompileStatic
class Foo<T> { 
    T member
}
```

And a specific subclass that works on Lists of Doubles. Easy enough, right?

```
@CompileStatic
class DoubleListFoo extends Foo<List<Double>> {

    void bar() {
        println member.size()
    }
}
```

Won't compile in Maven:

```
[ERROR] DoubleListFoo.groovy:[12,9] 3. ERROR in DoubleListFoo.groovy (at line 12)
[ERROR] println member.size()
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Groovy:[Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#size(). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
```

Compiles just fine from within IntelliJ. What's going on?

Maven version:

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T13:58:10-07:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.3
Java version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Groovy version:

```
groovyc -version
Groovy compiler version 2.4.3
Copyright 2003-2013 The Codehaus. http://groovy.codehaus.org/
```

FWIW, this is a simple test case I made when a more complicated class wouldn't compile with the error "Cannot assign value of type T to variable of type double[]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The official [Groovy documentation on Maven integration](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/tools-groovyeclipse.html) says the latest available version of the groovy-batch compiler is 2.3.7. That's not true, 2.4.3 [is available](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch).

The issue I found was [reported as a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7182) against the 2.3.7 compiler, and the bug was fixed in 2.3.11 and 2.4.3.